# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript does not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, client-side-scripting, registerclientscriptblock

I am currently in the process of migrating an old system to another server and when I tested the application, my popup windows displays a blank page. Please see below the code which is used to display my popup message:

```
Private Sub ShowPopUp(ByVal myID As String, ByVal request As String, ByVal windowType As String, ByVal code As String)
    Dim popupScript As String = "<script language='javascript'>" & _
                                    "window.open('NewWindow.aspx?windowType=" & windowType & "&id=" & myID & _
                                    "&code=" & code & "&popup=" & request & "&kind=3', 'CustomPopUp', " & _
                                    "'width=700, height=400, menubar=no, resizable=yes')" & _
                                "</script>"

    Page.RegisterStartupScript("PopupScript", popupScript)
End Sub
```

Now this used to work perfectly on the old site and on local. However, once transferred to the new server, I keep getting the warning that `Page.RegisterStartupScript is obsolete` and that it should be changed to `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`. So I did the changes, please see below:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "PopupScript", popupScript, True)
```

However, these doesn't work. It shows a blank page on my popup contrary to the result of running the application on my local with the 'old' way which shows my desired output.

Comment: so the window open is firing and you are getting a blank page right? whats the url of that page?

Comment: yes it is firing but i get a blank page. this is the URL: `NewWindow.aspx?windowType=PLHI&id=52000&code=C&popup=True&kind=3` thank you!!

Comment: Is this NewWindow.aspx on the same directory level as the page from where you are firing window.open?

Comment: yes it is. I got it to display now. However, this just solves one part of my general problem. whenever I run my solution locally on the server, this popup displays the window. However, when I try to access the website through a public URL, the popup just displays a blank page. Any luck you might know anything about this bug? Thank you very mucH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be ideally

```
Private Sub ShowPopUp(ByVal myID As String, ByVal request As String, ByVal windowType As String, ByVal code As String)
    Dim popupScript As String = String.Format("window.open('\NewWindow.aspx?windowType={0}&id={1}&code={2}&popup={3}&kind=3', '{4}', '{5}')",
            windowType, 
            myID, 
            code, 
            request,
            "CustomPopUp",
            "width=700, height=400, menubar=no, resizable=yes" )

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("PopupScript", popupScript, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. this works well. however, i had to remove the '/' and change it to an '\' on the popupScript. By the way, this just solves one part of my general problem. whenever I run my solution locally on the server, this popup displays the window. However, when I try to access the website through a public URL, the popup just displays a blank page. Any luck you might know anything about this bug? Thank you very mucH!

Comment: sorry. the code was untested. tell me your local and server urls. the relative paths

Comment: sorry, i don't think I get you. hehe. i'm new to these stuff since I am usually just tasked to program the code and not of the migration. thanks.